# Need help in playing audio files when button is clicked (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So here’s my code that I am working on. This is for a drum machine project. I have successfully created the buttons and I need help in making the audio file play once the buttons are clicked.
The src will be filled with links to audio files, and my project tells me to put a  element inside a button element.

Here’s the code:

```
import React from “react”;
import ReactDom from “react-dom”;

const sounds = [
{
idnum: “1”,
id: “Q”,
src: “1.html”,
},
{
idnum: “2”,
id: “W”,
src: “2.html”,
},
{
idnum: “3”,
id: “E”,
src: “3.html”,
},
{
idnum: “4”,
id: “A”,
src: “4.html”,
},
{
idnum: “5”,
id: “S”,
src: “5.html”,
},
{
idnum: “6”,
id: “D”,
src: “6.html”,
},
{
idnum: “7”,
id: “Z”,
src: “7.html”,
},
{
idnum: “8”,
id: “X”,
src: “8.html”,
},
{
idnum: “9”,
id: “C”,
src: “9.html”,
},
];

class Button extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
audioSource: “not clicked”,
};
this.soundOn = this.soundOn.bind(this);
}
/* soundOn() {
return sounds.src.play();
} */

// I know the above method will not work. I just had it to check if my buttons were working.

render() {
const buttonData = sounds.map((info) => (
<button className=“drum-pad” id={info[“idnum”]} onClick={this.soundOn}>
{info[“id”]}
));
return buttonData;
}
}
export default Button;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as you click handler:

```
soundOn = info => {
  var audio = new Audio(info.src);
  audio.play();
}
```

And put this in the `onClick` prop:

```
<button
  // you need a key prop
  key={info.idnum}
  className=“drum-pad”
  id={info[“idnum”]}
  onClick={() => this.soundOn(info)}
>
  {info.id}
</button>
```

Also, you may get better UX if you preload the audio files:

```
const sounds = [
  {
    idnum: “1”,
    id: “Q”,
    src: “1.html”,
    audio: new Audio("1.html"),
  },
]
```

And use this handler:

```
soundOn = info => {
  info.audio.play();
}
```